React big calendar alignment issue
React Big Calendar
Problem
I'm integrating React Big Calendar into my project, but I'm facing an issue where the header alignment is incorrect specifically in the Day and Week views. The headers do not align properly with the columns of the calendar grid below them.
Expected Behavior
The header (dates/times) in the Day and Week views should align properly with the columns in the calendar grid.
Actual Behaviour
The headers are misaligned, with the grid columns below not matching the header widths.

To clarify the issue youre having, "When you integrate React Big Calendar into youre current project, the styling is breaking for the calendar component or not being rendered as expected."

To clarify, the issue I'm experiencing is not related to the entire styling breaking but rather a specific misalignment between the headers and the columns in the Day and Week views. The headers (dates/times) don't align properly with the grid columns below them. Any advice would be appreciated!
